# Nuance between "toujours est-il que" and "il n’empêche que"

Tags: expressions

> C'est peut-être la beauté intérieure qui compte, mais **toujours est-il que** les concurrents sont tous des gravures de mode.
>
> C'est peut-être la beauté intérieure qui compte, mais **ça n’empêche que** les concurrents sont tous des gravures de mode.

Some sources have it that you can use these two expressions interchangeably, but I can’t help but feel that the use of "ça n’empêche que" is out of place in this instance. Perhaps, there is indeed a subtle difference, or am I reading too much into things here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can indeed be used interchangeably. However, "ça n'empêche que" implies that the candidates look really is important. "Toujours est-il que" insists a bit less on that idea (Which could actually match the "subtle difference" you are looking for).

Another interesting element : "toujours est-il que" is way more polite. "ça n'empêche que" is used orally and can be considered slightly familiar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Merci. So I wonder if « n'empêche que » is an emphatic version of « toujours est-il que »? If so, in the following example, you can use « n'empêche que » as a strong admonition, while « toujours est-il que » is for a mild reminder that  she shouldn't have come back, correct?

Comment: « *Je comprends ce que vous ressentez, mais {**ça n'empêche que** / **toujours est-il que**} vous n’auriez pas dû revenir ici.* ».

Comment: As a native speaker, I would indeed use it that way. However I am not entirely sure that everyone would get that difference. As I said before, I use "ça n'empêche que " orally more often.

Answer (score 2):

Les différentes formes sont interchangeables avec peu de différences :

- il n'empêche que ... (on ne dit pas ça n'empêche). formule insistante, et parlée
- toujours est-il que ... . forme plus stylée
- quoi qu'il en soit ... . forme plus stylée
- toutefois ... . forme courte
- néanmoins ... . idem
- cependant ... . idem